# Call a fragment inside onAdClosed() method

Tags: java, android, admob

I am having a strange problem. I am calling next fragment in method `onAdClosed()` when an interstitial ad is displayed to the user and the user closes it. below is my code for that purpose

```
myInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onAdOpened() {
                                // Code to be executed when the ad is displayed.

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdClosed() {

                                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

                                FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                                transaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
                                TestFragment newCustomFragment = new TestFragment();
                                transaction.replace(((ViewGroup) view.getParent()).getId(), newCustomFragment);
                                transaction.commit();

                            }
                        });
```

It works fine on new API's but I am having a problem in API 19. Problem is that ad closes but the next fragment does not call. After that, I wrapped my code inside a handler and that works for me i.e

```
@Override
                            public void onAdClosed() {

                               Handler handler_delete = new Handler();
                                handler_delete.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {

                                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

                                        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                                        transaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);
                                        TestFragment newCustomFragment = new TestFragment();
                                        transaction.replace(((ViewGroup) view.getParent()).getId(), newCustomFragment);
                                        transaction.commit();

                                    }
                                }, 300);

                            }
                        });
```

the problem gets solved but I am having Illegal State Exceptions sometimes. What should I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IllegalStateExceptions` throw when you `replace` fragment after `onSaveInstanceState` call. You have two way to fix this

1. You can using `commitAllowingStateLoss` instead of `commit`
2. Make your `Handler` global variable and call `Handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);` insde `onPause` of current fragment to remove execute `replace`